# catch [error] GenServer #PID<0.1278.0> terminating

Tags: elixir, genstage

Is it possible to catch a possible error within `handle_events` which creates this exception?

```
[error] GenServer #PID<0.1278.0> terminating
```

I tried listening in the consumer to the callback `def terminate(reason, state) do` but is not being called.

I am wondering if genstage has some kind of error handling I can use without having to wrap `handle_events` in a try/catch

```
  def handle_events(events, _from, _state) do
    # just post the events to an external service
    # after some trivial transformations
    # events might be bad encoded or some other error
    # might happen and genserver will terminate
    post_events(events)

    {:noreply, [], state}
  end
```

Comment: Smells like an XY problem. Do you want to prevent it from terminating? What exactly causes this error? Might the permissive clause of `handle_events` accepting everything help? How exactly do you process events? Please show the content of your `handler_events` at least.

Comment: Imagine a flow of events reaching handle_events and one of them is somehow corrupted and it terminates the genserver avoiding rest of the events be processed through.

Comment: Corrupted meaning what? Seems like your handler inside `handle_events` does a restrictive pattern match on the event or like. If that’s the case wrap it with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1) and skip-log invalids.

Comment: `with good_events <- filter(events), do: post_events(good_events)` should help.

Comment: For example, when posting them to an external service through HTTPoison one of those events might raise ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Poison.Encoder.BitString.chunk_size/3 and rest of them wont be posted and the genserver will terminate

Comment: Do you use banged `HTTPoison.encode!`? If yes, switch to `HTTPoison.encode` and discard bad events.

Comment: I havent control over HTTPoison, its used internaly from the package I am using (elastix) which checking the source code its using encode!

Comment: Do you know what’s the difference between _good_ and _corrupted_ event? Can you distinguish the upfront before passing to `post_events`?

Comment: Probably before sending it to Elastix I could encode myself the events with HTTPoison.encode and discard the bad ones.

Comment: But was wondering if there is something more generic, in case some other error happens to dont stop the flow

Comment: Anything generic is unlikely suitable here because AFAIU you want to _process_ proper ones and there is a single bottleneck `post_events` that either blows up or not. Even `try`-`rescue` won’t work as you want since when `N`th event is corrupted the control flow will be passed to `rescue` block, whoioch is not what you want. So, the only way IMHO is to `Enum.filter` with `Poison.encode`.

Comment: Also, you could have spawned a separate task per each event, but that’s also inapplicable due to `post_events` expects to receive a bunch. not a single event.

Comment: Spawn separated tasks is a good idea also, I ended solving this exactly error, my idea was to see if there is anything more generic like if handle events raises an error you catch it in terminate/1 and relaunch the consumer and it keeps processing the next events but this will have to do for now.